# Deleting a line that starts with a particular number in a text file

Tags: java, io

I've been trying to come up with a class that deletes a line from a text file that starts with a particular number.
What I currently have doesn't show any code errors and also runs without erros; shows "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" on netbeans, but doesn't do anything to the line, or any part of the textfile whatsoever, let alone delete the intended line.

Could anyone please look at my code and please advise me on what I might have done wrong, or is missing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Heres my code:

```
package Database;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Edit {

  public void removeLineFromFile(String file, String lineToRemove) {

    try {

      File inFile = new File("/D:/TestFile.txt/");

      if (!inFile.isFile()) {
        System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
        return;
      }

      //Construct the new file that will later be renamed to the original filename.
      File tempFile = new File(inFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tmp");

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

      String line = null;

      //Read from the original file and write to the new
      //unless content matches data to be removed.
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        if (!line.trim().equals(line.startsWith(lineToRemove))) {

          pw.println(line);
          pw.flush();
        }
      }
      pw.close();
      br.close();

      //Delete the original file
      if (!inFile.delete()) {
        System.out.println("Could not delete file");
        return;
      }

      //Rename the new file to the filename the original file had.
      if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile))
        System.out.println("Could not rename file");

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Edit edit = new Edit();
    edit.removeLineFromFile("/D:/TestFile.txt/", "2013001");
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `/D:/TestFile.txt/` is the path to your file?

Comment: Are you just building and expecting your code to run?

Comment: Yes. That's the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your logic ... you are saying if the line equals to itself that starts with something which will never happen unless the line only consist of the line you want to remove

```
if (!line.trim().equals(line.startsWith(lineToRemove))
```

i think needs to be just

```
if (!line.startsWith(lineToRemove))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the if condition to:

```
if (!line.startsWith(lineToRemove)) {

          pw.println(line);
          pw.flush();
        }
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks guys. That was so fast! Darshan Mehta's changes did the trick. Thank you so much again.

Comment: If you think my answer has helped you solve the problem then you can accept it as correct answer.